# Is it bad to extend Angular with additional methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on an application and there are a few methods Angular does not furnish which I find useful. I started a file to extend Angular with the desired methods instead of creating a utility service and injecting it (which seems cumbersome for simple - jQuery-esque -  methods).

So, I'm sticking my head out to ask if this is a good idea? Are there reasons to avoid this practice?

e.g. `angular.extensions.js`

```
// Angular has been previously loaded

;(function() {

  angular.extend(angular, {

    isEmptyObject: function(obj) {
      var name;
      for ( name in obj ) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    // etc. for simple helpers

  })

})();
```

Comment: `return Object.keys(obj).length == 0;`

Comment: @zerkms `jQuery`'s `$.isEmptyObject` function uses something similar to the code in the question.  Not sure why exactly, perhaps there is a false positive the length, or perhaps it's a performance thing. But they probably have a good reason for the iteration form.

Comment: Nice, I stole my example from jQuery 2.0.3. We're able to support ES5 in our application, so @zerkms's examples is an improvement. I imagine jQuery does not have the luxury of using Object.keys, or would have to expand their method with some ES5 features detection down the road.

Comment: @AlexWayne it's for browser compatibility. Object.keys would probably make IE8 puke.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it's technically okay, but probably a bit taboo style-wise. Consider a new developer joining your team and sees `angular.generatePuppy()` in your codebase. He googles `angular.generatePuppy()` and can't find any documentation or references to it in the Angular API and frustration ensues, although slightly lessened by google results for puppies. If you've created a utility service, it's easy as pie to inject it anywhere you may need it. It's no additional work once you've got it setup, and in my opinion, will make the code a bit more readable as there becomes a clear line between what you've written and what Angular has provided.

Comment: Interesting *angle*. I am definitely trying to be consistent with existing, simple, utility methods and not add obscure functionality to the angular space. But it makes sense that it becomes misleading as to what the angular API is intended to provide and officially supports.

Comment: "angle"... I see what you did there.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely fine technically, so long as you don't overwrite existing properties.  But organizationally, it seems like a bad idea?

Why not have your own global object named `utils` or something instead?

```
window.utils = {
  isEmptyObject: function(obj) { ... }
};
```

In general, don't mess with a vendor library unless you absolutely must.  Even if it's fine now, perhaps a future version may use that property or work in a different way.

And from a maintainability standpoint, a future programmer may think `angular.isPlainObject` is part of the angular framework. And wouldn't think to check that that code really works when debugging something.  They might have no idea that your project implements it's own version of this, since it's namespaced on a vendor library.

---

In short, you probably can, and it'll probably be fine. But you really shouldn't.

Comment: From the organizational perspective, I wanted my method to be next to Angular's `isDefined`, `isObject` etc. But there are good points here on why my example is problematic.

Comment: Convenience vs maintainability is a constant balancing act.  Everything always global is convenient, but unmaintainable.  Everything deeply nested in namespaces is maintainable but inconvenient.  Where that balance is can be tricky to find.